# In Vim, show path of file from where the code autocompletion is coming from

Tags: vim, autocomplete

In Vim, when doing auto completion with `^n`, I see autocompletion suggestions from the current file as well as different files all mixed together.

I would like to get a behavior similar to what is shown on the below picture, i.e. display the path of the file containing the suggestion if the suggestion is coming from file other than the current one.

[image]

Comment: Hmm, from that screenshot it seems like you already have what you are asking.

Comment: @romainl that screenshot is what I’m trying to achieve, not what I currently have.

Comment: What is shown in the screenshot is the default behaviour. The right question to ask is not "how to obtain that?" but "why don't I have that?". And we will need to take a look at your config to take a shot at answering it.

Comment: @romainl I tried on both macOS with vim `8.2.2200` and ubuntu with vim `8.2.1897` with no `.vimrc` and I always observe this behavior. I also tried with a completely new user on ubuntu and got the same result.

Comment: `$ mkdir /tmp/compl && cd $_ && echo "foo" > file1 && echo "bar" > file2 && vim -Nu NONE file1 file2` then do `o<C-n>`. You should have `foo` from the current buffer and `bar file2` from the other buffer [in the completion menu](https://i.imgur.com/LTMZyhb.png).